# How to get an image response in Swagger 3.0

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-3.0

Image response is not coming from swagger,

```
/Legends/icons:
    get:
      tags:
        - Legend Controller
      summary: Get legend icon
      description: Proxy for icon request for legends which use one.
      operationId: GetLegendIcon
      parameters:
        - name: IconUrl
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
            nullable: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          content:
            image/png: {}
        '500':
          description: ''
      security:
        - bearerAuth: []
```

Error : can't parse JSON. Raw result:

This is my swagger version openapi: 3.0.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akuEO.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1IGB.jpg)

---

Controller Code:

```
 [HttpGet("icons")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: nameof(GetLegendIcon), summary: "Get legend icon", "Proxy for icon request for legends which use one.")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileContentResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status424FailedDependency)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetLegendIcon([FromQuery] GetLegendIconRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var iconUrl = new Uri(geoServerConfiguration.Current.BaseUrl);
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(request.IconUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out _) || !request.IconUrl.StartsWith($"{iconUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}") && !iconUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path).EndsWith(ApiRequests.AllowedIconUrlsSubPath))
        {
            return BadRequest(ValidationErrors.InvalidLegendIconUrl);
        }

        return File(await _cachedLayerDetailsManager.GetLegendIconCachedAsync(request.IconUrl, cancellationToken), "image/png");
    }
```

---

I am expecting image response

Comment: The problem is that your server returns the `Content-Type: application/json` header instead of `image/png`. Review your controller code and server-side MIME type configurations.

Comment: In Controller code, image/png is returning as file type.
 return File(await _cachedLayerDetailsManager.GetLegendIconCachedAsync(request.IconUrl, cancellationToken), "image/png");

Comment: Can you add the full controller code and its annotations to your post?

Comment: @Helen I have attached the controller code in snippet.

Comment: If you add `[Produces("image/png")]`, does it resolve the issue?